# block bad server request while using lowest server overhead

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, exchange-server, http-status-code-400

Our web server is occasionally getting slammed with loads of requests for an (exchange server) file that doesn't exist on our (apache) web server:

autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

How can I respond to those requests in a way that requires the least load on our server?

(When these requests happen, our VPS memory usage spikes and goes over our RAM allocation.)

I want the server to respond, with the lowest overhead, telling them basically to go away; that file doesn't exist here; stop; bad request (you get the idea.)

Right now, the server returns a 404 error page which means that our WordPress installation is evoked. It returns our custom 404 WordPress error page. That involves a lot of overhead that I'd like to avoid.

I suspect that these requests come from some sort of hacking attempts, but I'm just guessing at that. At any rate, I just want to intercept them and block or stop them as quickly and efficiently as possible.

(I've put IP blocks on the IP addresses they come from but I think that is just playing whack-a-mole.)

I've put this in our htaccess file but it doesn't do what I want:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ "-" [forbidden,last]
</IfModule>
```

Is there something wrong with this rule?

Can I or should I use our htaccess file in another way to do what I want? Is there a better way to do it than using htaccess? Could we be returning something other than a 404 response? Perhaps a 400 or 403 response? How would we do that? We are on a VPS server to which I do not have direct access.

Comment: I also don't understand why it is returning a 404 page. Since the RewriteRule uses a forbidden flag, shouldn't it return a 403 response? Does that mean that the rule is written wrong and not being applied, or that something else in the htaccess file is over-riding this? (Following this in the file is the standard WordPress mod_rewrite code.)

Comment: While I have no way yet to head off the requests before they hit Apache, I'd still like to try to head them off before they hot WordPress. I've tried these variants:

`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ - [forbidden,last]
</IfModule>
`
(no quotes on the hyphen) and also this:

`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ "-" [forbidden,last]
</IfModule>
`

Comment: Sorry! I went over my comment editing time!

While I have no way yet to head off the requests before they hit Apache, I'd still like to try to head them off before they hot WordPress. I've tried these variants:

`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
`
(no quotes on the hyphen) and also this:

`
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^autodiscover/autodiscover.xml$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
`
But WordPress still kicks in with our theme's custom 404 error page.

Comment: I've also tried creating an autodiscover directory and putting an htaccess file in there with the mod_rewrite lines in place (and using only `^autodiscover.xml$` as my regex) but even with that, I still get WordPress with our 404 page when I make the request. Can anyone explain why all of these attempts at using an htaccess rewrite are not working?

Answer (score 0):

"No direct access" means you can't install software?

I'd totally recommend setting up nginx as a reverse proxy, but if that's out of the question because of no local admin: use a service like CloudFlare and use page rules (which runs the reverse proxy for you, and more).

You don't want anything unnecessary to reach apache if you run pre-fork mpm (which you probably do because of mod_php), as it will spawn lots of processes to handle parallel clients, and it is relatively slow in starting them. Additionally, once the storm is over, they'll be killed again (depending on your setting for MaxSpareServers).

Regarding MaxSpareServers, and a way to at least contain the damage this does:

IF (you might not be) you run apache's mpm_prefork (MPM = Multi-Processing Modules, basically what "engine" apache uses; most PHP-setups with mod_php run mpm_prefork), apache needs a child to handle each parallel request.

Now, when 100 requests come in at the same time, apache will spawn 100 (or less, if MaxRequestWorkers is set below 100), childs to handle them. That's VERY costly, because each of those processed needs to start and will take up memory) and can result in a Denial-Of-Server for all intents and purposes as your VPS starts to swap and everything gets slowed down.

Once this request storm is over, apache is left with 100 child processes, and will start to remove some of them until it reaches whatever has been set as MaxSpareServers. If there are no spare servers, new requests will have to wait in line for a child to handle them. To users, that's basically "the server doesn't respond".

If you can't put something in front of apache, can you change (or have somebody change) the apache config? You will have some success if you limit MaxRequestWorkers, aka the maximum number of childs apache can spawn (and therefore the maximum number of parallel requests that can be handled). If you do, the server will still appear unresponsive in high load times, but it won't affect the system as much, as your processes won't start to use SWAP instead of RAM and become terribly slow.

Comment: Correct, can't set up nginx because we can't install software.

Cloudflare to head off these requests before they hit our server is undoubtedly a good idea too, but may not be possible either. And sorry, but your explanation about MaxSpareServers is over my head.

Comment: It was too long for a comment, so I've edited my answer with more information about how apache's mpm prefork works and what role MaxSpareServers plays.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that detailed explanation. Can I determine if our VPS runs apache's mpm_prefork by, for example, a php `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: Yes. The "Loaded Modules" section in phpinfo() will contain `prefork`.

Comment: Seems that we do not have the prefork module. Are there other alternate modules that do similar things, which we might have instead?

Comment: Possibly. What module do you run? Do you even run apache at all (you don't necessarily have to)?

Comment: Yes, we are running Apache. When I search phpinfo() output, I find no reference to prefork. I googled other alternative modules but also found no reference to worker or event or ITK.

Answer (score 0):

Any attempt to *Deny* access to the file, whether via Deny or an [F] forbidden flag, results in WordPress kicking in and responding with a 404 error page.

To avoid this, I have created a custom 421 error page (which seemed most appropriate), placed it outside of the WordPress directory, and used an htaccess Redirect from the bad-request file name to the custom error page.

`Redirect /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml /path/to/error-421-autodiscover-xml.php`

This returns the custom error page (only 1KB) without WordPress being invoked. Creating a custom error page specific to the one file with the bad-request file in the name of the error code file should help to identify these calls in our log files.

If you ran an Exchange server elsewhere for email, then it might be appropriate to redirect from the web server to the Exhange server using htacess on the web server. An appropriate htaccess rule might be:

`RedirectMatch 302 (?i)^/autodiscover/(.*)$ https://mail.example.com/autodiscover/$1`

See: https://glennmatthys.wordpress.com/2013/10/14/redirect-autodiscover-urls-using-htaccess/

@janh is certainly right that a mechanism to intercept the request before it even hits our Apache server would be ideal, but it is beyond what we can do right now.

(The /autodiscover/autodiscover.xml seems to be a file used by Exchange servers to route traffic to the mail server. According to our web hosting company, it is not unusual for Apache servers to be hit with requests for this file. Some of these requests may come from malicious bots searching for access to a mail server; some may come from misconfigured smart phone email clients or other misdirected requests intended for an Exchange server.)